# Analyze categorical data when there cannot be "negative" influence

Tags: categorical-data, chi-squared-test, compositional-data

Suppose there are 1000 items given 5 labels [A,B,C,D,E]. You observe  [750,200,25,25,0]. You want to find out whether items are biased towards being given certain labels.

In a standard chi-squared GOF analysis, you could compare to a null hypothesis  of p=[0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2]. The test would of course be significant, and yields the standardized residuals [43.48,0,-13.8,-13.8,-15.8]. You would conclude that items are biased to be in labeled A, and biased against being labeled C, D, and E.

What if you want to instead conclude that items are very biased towards being labeled A, biased towards being labeled B, and perhaps slightly (or non-significantly) biased towards being labeled C and D. In other words, if you consider the entire dataset, items are labeled "B" exactly as often as you'd expect (residual is 0). However, if you consider only the items that were not labeled "A", [200,25,25,0], it would look like items are labeled "B" far more than you would expect by chance.

How would you analyze data to answer a question like this? Is this even reasonable to do? It seems intuitively reasonable that in the presence of a very strong bias towards "A" and a relatively weaker bias towards "B", you could get situations where the counts of "B" look similar to the counts expected by chance, but you would want to conclude a bias towards "B" rather than a bias away from "C, D, and E".

Comment: Your null hypotheses on the qui-square test does not need to be all probabilities being equal. You could have, for instance $p=(0.7; 0.2; 0.04; 0.04; 0.02)$. For instance, in a pregnancy, it is more common for a woman to carry a single child than twins, and it is even rarer to have triplets.

Comment: @Ertxiem Sure, but my null is actually flat. To give a concrete example: suppose I want to examine the influence of an advertisement that primes the color choices "red" and "blue" on a subsequent color preference. If my null is that people are equally likely to choose red, green, blue, yellow, but after the ad they choose 75% red and 25% blue, a chi-squared test would tell me that my advertisement successfully primed red, left blue at chance, and successfully primed AGAINST green and yellow. This does not make intuitive sense to me - it makes more sense that the ad primed red and blue.